# VMWare Workstation hdd issue

Tags: vmware-workstation

When i run my virtual machine, it clogs down my hard disc and OS freezes.

What can cause this?

P.s. feel free to ask for additional info. I just don't know what exactly i should state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing vmware tools helped.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this with severe disk fragmentation, on both the drive that holds the VM and inside the VM's virtual disk. It may help to defrag both, starting with the hosting drive.

(For what it's worth, I've only seen it on WinXP hosting a WinXP VM.)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely merge split VMDKs if you have them (it's the default when you create the VM).
Convert the VMDK to a fixed sized virtual disk instead of an expanding one.
Then also delete snapshots if you have any and run a defrag on the host before starting up the VM.
When you have expanding VMDKs they pretty much clog the entire system and freeze up everything.